# Unable to destroy widget in tkinter.

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want some widgets to be created on clicking a checkbutton. Then I need them to hide and re-appear on toggling a checkbutton. I am able to create the widgets, but unable to destroy them. I have tried `grid_remove()`, `grid_forget()` and `destroy()`. The statement intended to hide or destroy them seems to be getting executed, but the widget stays. No error is reported.

Here is some code to reproduce the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Checkbutton")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.var = BooleanVar()
        cb = Checkbutton(self, text="Show title",
            variable=self.var, command=self.onClick)
        cb.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def onClick(self):
        widget = Label(self, text="Enter text")
        if self.var.get():
             self.master.title("Checkbutton")
             widget.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
             self.master.title("")
             widget.destroy()   

root = Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, each time you click on `CheckButton`, `onClick` create *new* `Label` widget. And your if-else condition destroy that new widget, but not the widget, that was created earlier. You should link your widget through `self.widget = Label`. Now function will delete element, which was created in past function call.

Your code will be:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Checkbutton")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.var = BooleanVar()
        cb = Checkbutton(self, text="Show title",
            variable=self.var, command=self.onClick)
        cb.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def onClick(self):
        if self.var.get():
             self.widget = Label(self, text="Enter text")
             self.master.title("Checkbutton")
             self.widget.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
             self.master.title("")
             self.widget.destroy()   

root = Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did not think of that. My problem is solved now. Thanks